# VirtualQueryEx / ReadProcessMemory

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

One week ago I started making a project to scan another processes memory. First I was thinking in just inject a DLL into the processes and then access its memory, but due to all difficulty I started doing this with VirtualQueryEx / ReadProcessMemory APIs.
Some doubts emerged in my mind, below is the code:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  PIDHandle: THandle;
  PID: dword;
  MemInfo: MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION;
  SysInfo: SYSTEM_INFO;
  PageSize, MemStart, ReceivedBytes: cardinal;
  Buff: PChar;
  IsWow64Process: TIsWow64Process;
  IsWow64: BOOL;

    while (VirtualQueryEx(PIDHandle, Pointer(MemStart), MemInfo, SizeOf(MemInfo)) > 0) do
      begin
        if ((MemInfo.State = MEM_COMMIT) and (not (MemInfo.Protect = PAGE_GUARD)
            or (MemInfo.Protect = PAGE_NOACCESS))) then
          begin
            if (0<>MemInfo.Protect and PAGE_READWRITE) then
              begin
                GetMem(Buff, MemInfo.RegionSize);
                if (ReadProcessMemory(PIDHandle, Pointer($00636ED0), Buff,
                                        MemInfo.RegionSize, ReceivedBytes)) then
                  begin
                    Memo1.Lines.Append(PAnsiChar(Buff));
                  end;
                FreeMem(Buff);
              end;
          end;
      MemStart:= MemStart + MemInfo.RegionSize;
    end;
  CloseHandle(PIDHandle);
  end;
```

First All - This while method:

```
while (VirtualQueryEx(PIDHandle, Pointer(MemStart), MemInfo, SizeOf(MemInfo)) > 0) do
...
 MemStart:= MemStart + MemInfo.RegionSize;
```

Am I scanning all the memory addresses? Or it's just 'jumping' addresses without reading??!
Second and most important problem- I'm using notepad to make tests, and my objective is to read some string wrote there. If I make like this:

```
       if (0<>MemInfo.Protect and PAGE_READWRITE) then
              begin
                GetMem(Buff, MemInfo.RegionSize);
                if (ReadProcessMemory(PIDHandle, Pointer($00636ED0), Buff,
                                        MemInfo.RegionSize, ReceivedBytes)) then
                  begin
                    Memo1.Lines.Append(PAnsiChar(Buff));
                  end;
                FreeMem(Buff);
              end;
```

Passing the Address directly in the ReadProcessMemory, it works and get the first letter(or first byte) of my string. Remembering Buff is PChar... But if I do the same thing but ReadProcessMemory like this:

```
if (ReadProcessMemory(PIDHandle, MemInfo.BaseAddress, Buff,
  MemInfo.RegionSize, ReceivedBytes)) then
      begin
          Memo1.Lines.Append(PAnsiChar(Buff));
      end;
   FreeMem(Buff);
   end;
```

It add on the Memo a bunch of chinese and invalid characters. How can I automatically scan every single memory address and get my string wrote there? Any questions about the code, just ask-me... Waiting for your help

Comment: It's a mistake trying to interpret this memory as text. It isn't text. You want to display it the same way as a hex editor.

Comment: Yes, more or less like this. Have some Hex Editors that have a function to search an exact text string in the memory. I want to do this, search for some kind of string in the memory...

Answer (score 0):

Allocate one extra character in Buff and initialize it with zero. I'm guessing Memo1.Lines.Append wants a null terminated string, the garbage characters are probably whatever happened to be in memory after Buff.

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you said, but I can see all the received buff in the memo, and it's only garbage. Only the first line is: RESCHIT
everything else is garbage

Comment: Most of the memory in a process is normally garbage when interpreted as text. You are reading notepad memory for testing? Notepad uses unicode characters (16-bit characters) so most latin language characters will have a zero high byte. If ansi characters are interpreted as unicode, then you will get total garbage with lots of chinese etc, (because the high byte of each character is the next character). I'm not following exactly what you are trying to achieve. Dump the memory of a process into a text field?

Comment: Not exactly all the memory into a text field. But I want to parses every memory address with Read/Write property to search for a string. This string I'm searching obviously will be in text (ASCII or Unicode), but how to get? That's my question.

Answer (score 0):

To get the first memory address do this :

```
var
sysinfo : TSystemInfo;
GetSystemInfo(sysinfo);
start : DWORD;
begin
start := DWORD(sysinfo.lpMinimumApplicationAddress);
end;
```

You are getting garbage because an 0 occurss in the string before all memory is shown so do this use

```
var
   mybuffer : String;
begin
   SetLength(mybuffer,MemInfo.RegionSize);
   CopyMemory(@mybuffer[1],Buff,MemInfo.RegionSize);
   Memo1.Lines.Add(mybuffer);

end;
```

Comment: Not working because notepad does not use ascii encoding code your own application in delphi 7 using a tmemo and test it

Comment: I'm on delphi 2010... any way to convert it?!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for dll injection (and other fun techniques), maybe you should a look at here?
https://sites.google.com/site/delphibasics/system/app/pages/search?scope=search-site&q=dll+injection